# How do I install qt-faststart on Wamp?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, qt-faststart

I have installed FFMPEG on WAMP 2. However I believe I also need qt-faststart in order to quickly load the meta data in MP4 files. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You need qt-faststart to make MP4 files streamable. Here is a Windows build of qt-faststart.exe: http://notboring.org/downloads/video/qt-faststart.zip

Will that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to qt-faststart is MP4Creator.
http://mp4creator.sourceforge.net/

Commandline: mp4creator -optimize videofile.mp4

I found it to be much faster than qt-faststart on slow disks (like an SD card)

Sorry, Mike ;)

Comment: No big deal. :-) Whatever solves the problem. I'll look into MP4Creator and perhaps even start recommending it over my qt-faststart program if it's the right solution.

Comment: FYI: I debugged qt-faststart and found the culprit. While copying the rest of the file it copied 1K at a time, which is terribly slow on a SD card. I changed the COPY_BUFFER_SIZE to 32M, malloced the copy_buffer and the processing on a sample file decreased from 1707 seconds to 2 seconds.

Comment: s/2 seconds/4 seconds/. After https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/f4d9148fe282879b9fcc755767c9c04de9ddbcfa and the 2 following patches qt-faststart is as fast as mp4creator.

Comment: qt-faststart is now also available as a second pass in ffmpeg:
http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-October/010439.html

-movflags +faststart
Run a second pass to put the moov at the beginning of the file